# How can I validate a potential public ssh key part?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm building a small service where users may upload their public SSH key in order to access a Mercurial repository (via SSH). I'd like to verify that whatever the users paste is:

- valid (`ssh-keygen -l -f pasted_key_put_in_a_file` exit code is 0)
- not the private part of a their key pair <--- this is what I'm looking for a command to do

From what I understand, `ssh-keygen -l -f ...` doesn't say whether the key part inspected is the public or private part.

Is there a way to verify that a file does *not* contain/represent the private part of a key pair?

Comment: despite this being about certificates, this really looks like a programming (scripting/regex/pattern matching) question where the trouble is knowing what a public key looks like - this might be solved by requiring that the key is surrounded with the `---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----` padding?

Comment: I'm not sure - is knowing the details of the `ssh-keygen` tool security or programming knowledge?

Comment: so your question was constrained to the use of `ssh-keygen`?

Comment: No, but rather the format of a the private part of an (Open)SSH key pair, and the syntactic validation thereof. For that purpose, `ssh-keygen` seems to be a useful tool where I could trust that tool to do the job, and not care for implementation details of the actual format. I'd also assume the tool may validate other formats/representations.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `ssh-keygen -l -f private_key` will look for a matching `public_key` in the same directory as `private_key` and use that if found. But if there is no such (by name) matching public key part, the `private_file` will be tried and the program complains. So the command I thought couldn't be used, can in fact be used (as long as there's no public key part in a file next to it with a matching name).

Comment: You might want to add other measures to check for plausibility before writing arbitrary data to a file and executing `ssh-keygen` on it. The least concern here being a attack filling up your hard drive space.

Comment: Yes. Will not in this case though.